# Undefined variable: user (View: E:\PROJECTS\Ecommerce app\electrostore\resources\views\admin\components\topBar.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, undefined-variable

How to handle undefined variable when I have to include or extend that blade file in other files

Answer (score 0):

You can share your desired data in any blade file by [sharing data with those blades](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).

In your **AppServiceProvider**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() 
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() 
    {
        $user_id = 1; // For example
        $user = \App\Models\User::find($user_id);

        // Share to all blade files
        View::share('user', $user);

        // Or only in a specific blade file
        View::composer('admin.components.topBar', function ($view) use($user) {
            $view->share('user', $user);
        });
    }
}
```

Now, `$user` is available in all of your blade files.

Comment: I used this function in AppserviceProvider.php  

   public function boot()
    {
        $user = "Foobar";
        view()->share('user', $user);
    }
 but now i'm getting the other error trying to get property of non-object. for this
 $user->image

Comment: You should not pass `$user="Foobar";` to view, as it is not an object from \App\Models\User. You should get an object from this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable to the included view with
`@include('view.name', ['user' => $user])`. You can also check the document about this on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews